# How to record my keystrokes during a kata?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keystroke

To evaluate my performance doing a kata I want to record my keystrokes done during that kata. I want to compare keystrikes between katas so I can optimize to reduce keystrokes (use proper shortcuts).

Is there an tool that let's me do that similar to audio-recording or screen-grabbing? (I do not want to install an evil keylogger.)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It reads to me like "I want to log my keystrokes while doing something (code katas), but I don't want to install anything that logs my keystrokes".

Comment: Ken, thanks for asking. Yes I am aware that I will have to install some kind of recorder, but I do not want to go to some underground page and install some malware keylogger (as used for password hacking). Is there a key stroke recorder that is not connected to usual malware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) there is a plugin "IntelliJ Code Golf" in the list of JetBrains plugins. I noticed it first in IDEA 13.

For Eclipse I wrote a plugin [Keystrokes](http://hg.code-cop.org/org.codecop.keystrokes) that records all your keystrokes and short-cuts. An typical output after starting the recording would look like

```
ctrl-f6 
end left ctrl-shift-left "new Array" ctrl-space "l" enter 
ctrl-f11 up up down down enter (run test - OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one in the official Debian repository

> [logkeys](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/logkeys)
>
> a keylogger for GNU/Linux systems
>
> Logkeys is no more advanced than other available Linux keyloggers,
>   but is a bit more up to date, it doesn't unreliably repeat keys and it
>   should never crash your X. All in all, it just seems to work. It
>   relies on event interface of the Linux input subsystem. Once set, it
>   logs all common character and function keys, while also being fully
>   aware of Shift and AltGr key modifiers.

```
 sudo apt-get install logkeys
```